# How To Get Published Test Results from TFS 2010 Build, From Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, mstest

I am using Visual Studio 2012, but TFS 2010.

I have created a build with the default build template, that builds several C# solutions, runs tests, etc. At present, many of the unit tests fail. I can see from the build log that MSTEST has successfully published the build results to the TFS server.

BTW, the build was a "Partial Success". I would like to know why. That's why I'm looking for the test results.

In Visual Studio 2010, I would have used the Test Results and Test Runs windows to load the published results. These windows are missing in Visual Studio 2012. How can I get access to my test results (preferably without installing Visual Studio 2010).

Also, the full build log is not copied to the drop folder. Is there some way for me to find out what caused the "Partial Success"?

---

P.S. This is Visual Studio Professional 2012.

---

**UPDATE**

So, it says "Publishing results of test run ... to url". How do I get to see the test results?

Comment: When you look at the build results is there link to the Test Results (2010 was a long time ago, so can't remember, but in 2012+ there would be)

Comment: I believe there would be a link to the test results if the build had succeeded. Since it was a partial success, instead I get text that says "no test results", which is clearly false.

Comment: Does it say 9 out of 10 test passed or anything like that, because even on partial success it should say that and have a link to test results.

Comment: It says "no test results"

Answer (score 0):

View Menu -> Other Windows -> Test Results

Comment: Ok. This is bizarre. I just looked again, and saw a View->Other Windows->Load Test Results. I have no load tests, but I tried that anyway. It brought up the "Test Results" window. Also, it changed the "Load Test Results" menu item to "Test Results".

Comment: Unfortunately, when I get to the "Test Runs" window, and pull down "Connect to test run...", I don't get the choice to connect to TFS - that "Enter or select a controller machine name" is disabled.